# jQuery slideshow: Fade in first image

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fadein

I'm using this code for a slideshow and it works well:

**JS**

```
$(function(){
$('.fadein p:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){$('.fadein > :first-child').fadeOut(1500).next('p').fadeIn(1500).end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7g27j9gj/

What i want to change: Fade in the first image (currently it's immediately shown) but only at the first pass.

Thanks!

Comment: Any html would be great.

Comment: A working jsfiddle.net example would be helpful to understand how the slideshow is currently working

Comment: What do you mean exactly with fade in first image only at the first pass?

Comment: Do you want that in fades all images, then, when reaches the last and get back to the first, don't fade any of the images anymore?